How to include credentials plugin in Gradle app behind corporate proxy
I am creating a sample gradle app on my machine which is behind coroporate firewall and build.gradle.kts is as follows:
import nu.studer.gradle.credentials.domain.CredentialsContainer

plugins {
    application
    id("nu.studer.credentials") version "3.0"
}

val credentials: CredentialsContainer by project.extra
val repositoryUsername = credentials.getProperty("username") as String?
val repositoryPassword = credentials.getProperty("password") as String?

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "nexus"
        url = uri("nexus-package-url")
        credentials {
            username = repositoryUsername
            password = repositoryPassword
        }
    }
}

As I have to setup corporate nexus url, I have to pass credentials but Again for credentials to work respective plugin should be available. To me it seems like a circular dependency.
When I try to run ./gradlew :app:tasks --all for above configuration, it gets failed with below error message:
    * What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'nu.studer.credentials', version: '3.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'nu.studer.credentials:nu.studer.credentials.gradle.plugin:3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Could someone please suggest on this.
Thanks

Issue was due to newer Java 17 version (earlier for other apps I was using 11) as I missed certificate import in $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts. It was working fine until I was using the plugin same as one that I was using for the apps with Java 11. When I started using the new plugin in build.gradle, it started failing with the error.
I simply copied the previously used java 11 cacerts to Java17 path and plugin started getting downloaded.
cp /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts /Users/test/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.11/Contents/Home/lib/security/

